# How to extract element from JSON array and put into another array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json

How to convert this

```js
[{"col":"ClientPolicy","st":"false","id":"1"},{"col":"Department","st":"true","id":"2"}]
```

to

```js
[{"ClientPolicy":false,"Department":true}]
```

this  in react js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function. Try like below.

```js
const input = [{"col":"ClientPolicy","st":"false","id":"1"},{"col":"Department","st":"true","id":"2"}];

const output = input.reduce((prevValue, { col, st }) => {
    prevValue[col] = typeof st === "string" ? JSON.parse(st) : st
    return prevValue;
}, {});

console.log([output]);
```

Comment: @sudesh sampath, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you, Can you suggest how to get output as this, (true false should be in boolean format.  [
  {
    "ClientPolicy": false
  ,
  
    "Department": true
  }
]

Comment: @sudeshsampath, I have updated the answer with boolean values !! Can you please mark this as the answer once you validated? Thanks!

Comment: boolean conversion is ok now, little more thing to do, the final output should be like this  [ { "ClientPolicy": false , "Department": true } ]  only one {} is required, can you suggest me Please

Comment: @sudeshsampath, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var array = [{
  "col": "ClientPolicy",
  "st": "false",
  "id": "1"
}, {
  "col": "Department",
  "st": "true",
  "id": "2"
}];

var cols = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.col] = Boolean(c.st);
  return a;
}, {});

var output = [];
output.push(cols);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: this is also correct